# How to escape question mark in SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis, special-characters

In Execute SQL Task, my sql statement contains a question mark.

This causes confusion since SSIS takes it as an input variable.

So, how to escape that? Backslash seems not working.

The SQL statement is like

```
Select Left(@title, PatIndex('%?%', CAST(@title AS varchar(100)) + '?')-2)
```

It extracts those non-double-byte characters (to the left) from a Unicode `string @title.`

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty answer would be to use a Variable. At the Control Flow level, click in the background, then right click in the background and select Variables. In the Variables Window, click Add Variable. Name it `QuerySource` and set the data type as String. Paste in your query above and then in your `Execute SQL Task`, change the source from Direct Input to Variable and then choose QuerySource.

Answer (score 0):

Use CHAR(53) instead:

```sql
DECLARE @title as varchar(100) = 'Some'+CHAR(63)+'Data'
Select Left(@title, PatIndex('%'+CHAR(63)+'%', CAST(@title AS varchar(100)) + CHAR(63))-2)
```